# Accessing a private Google sheet with a google cloud service account

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a private Google Spreadsheet and I’m trying to access it programmatically using Google Visualization/Google Charts. I've created the service account, and I have tried using the `google-auth-library` and `googleapis` npm packages to create an access token that I can then use to access the spreadsheet. But, when I try to use that access token to read from the spreadsheet, the request fails with HTTP code 401 (Unauthorized). What do I need to do in order to make this work?

This is my code:

```js
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');
const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');

const id = '{Spreadsheet ID}';
const sheetId = '{Sheet ID}';
const query = "{Query}";

async function getClient(){
    const client = auth.fromJSON(keys);
    client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
    console.log(client);
    return client;
}

async function main(){
    const client = await getClient();
    const token = await client.getAccessToken();
    console.log(token);
    console.log(token.token);
    const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&tq=${encodeURIComponent(query)}&access_token=${token.token}#gid=${sheetId}`;
    const res = await client.request({url});
    console.log(res);
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: did u share the file with the service account?

Comment: Are you using a Google Workspace or a regular gmail.com account?

Comment: @DavidSalomon I did share the file with the service account

Comment: @FernandoLara I am using a regular gmail.com account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I saw your script, I thought that it is required modifying the scope. I had got the same situation as you (the status code `401` using your endpoint). Unfortunately, it seems that your endpoint cannot be used using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`. So, for example, how about changing it as follows, and testing it again?

#### From:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

#### To:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

or

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your endpoint using the modified scope, I confirmed that no error occurred. But if you tested it and when an error occurs, please check other part, again.

Comment: Thank you! I had used the `spreadsheets.readonly` scope since I wasn't going to be writing any data, but I changed it to the full `spreadsheets` scope and the request worked!

Comment: @2pichar Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.